# LINQ seems to ignore part of Where clause (probably due to ICollection issue) during Mapping

Tags: c#, linq, mapping

let me use this sample data to make my problem clearer:

```
public class Booking

public override int Id { get; set; }
public int? AddressId { get; set; }
public virtual Address Adress { get; set; }
public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
public decimal? Hours { get; set; }



public class Address

public override int Id { get; set; }
public ICollection<Booking> Bookings{ get; set; }
```

Having these two entities when trying to do the following in Linq while mapping `Booking` to a `ListItemDto`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Booking, MyListItemDto>()
    .ForMember(t  => t.HoursSum, 
              map => map.MapFrom(e => e.Address.Bookings
                          .Where(b => b.Datum.Value == e.Datum.Value)
                          .Sum(b => b.Hours))
```

weirdly, the result is the Sum of all Hours of the `Bookings` of this `Address`(for every row).
 Meaning that the date clause seems to be completely ignored.

My brain can't get what the problem is but I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that I'm going from `Booking -> Address-> Bookings` and then comparing the values.
But database wise it's normal since each `Booking` has a unique `AddressId` but each `Address` can be related with many `Bookings` AND more than one `Booking` can exist in a given date.

I hope my problem is clear and that I'm providing enough information. If anyone needs something more, feel free to tell me.

Comment: For a sanity check, where you're invoking the Map, can you also run `address.Bookings.Where(b => b.Datum.Value == e.Datum.Value).Sum(b => b.Hours)` and check that value? I'm erring on the side that maybe the data isn't what you think it is. That, or AutoMapper is somehow manipulating the expression, but it won't be because of `ICollection`

Comment: Running the (equivalent) query in SQL Management Studio "proves" that the Date comparison isn't working. To put it simply in each row I get the result of this query:     SELECT SUM(Hours) FROM Booking WHERE AddressID = 12345  instead of getting the result of  SELECT SUM(Hours) FROM Booking WHERE AddressID = 12345 AND Date = '2016-04-12 00:00:00.000'

Comment: Well yes, but maybe the dates actually *do* match :) That's why I'm interested in the result if we ignore AutoMapper, because LINQ doesn't typically drop methods from it's chain :). The equivalent SQL query would be `SELECT SUM(HOURS) FROM Booking INNER JOIN Address ON Booking.AddressId = Address.ID WHERE Booking.Date = Address.Date`

Comment: I'm a bit confused or I didn't explain something correctly... But the e.Date is the Date of the Booking row, not of the Address.

So basically, for each Booking row I'm trying to get all the Bookings of the associated Address that exist in the same date...with the Booking of the row.

*These bookings should include the booking of the row actually, if that is understandable.

Comment: Yep - that's correct, which is why your SQL query *also* needs to filter on the dates as above. What I'm saying is, the booking dates may be the same as their address' dates - in which case the where is being executed, but it is always true

Comment: But in your SQL example the Address.Date doesn't make sense... There is no Date column in the Address table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108939/discussion-between-dimitris-g-and-rob).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my question since I found a solution to the problem:

The cause is that the expression is interpreted wrongly. Specifically the

```
.Where(b => b.Datum.Value == e.Datum.Value)
```

part is getting mixed up and in the query that is generated both b. and e. are considered to be the **same Booking**.
The solution is to actually do it like this:

```
map => map.MapFrom(e => e.Address.Bookings
                      .Select(b => new {b.Datum, b.Hours})
                      .Where(b => b.Datum.Value == e.Datum.Value)
                      .Sum(b => b.Hours))
```

That (for whatever reason, it doesn't look nice I know) solves the problem and the expression is translated to a correct query.
I'm assuming it's some sort of a bug with the version of Automapper we are using (3.3)

Cheers!